# SaveChangesAsync in EF Core IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use Entity Framework Core Identity in an ASP.NET Core application

I have created Database Context and its interface as follows:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>, IAppDbContext
{
    public AppDbContext (DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<AppUser> AppUser { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

public interface IAppDbContext
{
    DbSet<AppUser> AppUser { get; set; }

    int SaveChanges();
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Here the issue is, it shows an error in `AppDbContext`, stating

> 'AppDbContext' does not implement interface member
>   'IAppDbContext.SaveChangesAsync()'

If the AppDbContext is inherited from the `DbContext` insted of `IdentityDbContext` error would not appear, but to use Identity it should be inherited from `IdentityDbContext`.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's weird, because this error should shown in both cases. Anyway, `DbContext` doesn't have method:

```
Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
```

It has method:

```
Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
```

To get around this case, you should wrap `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync` method:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>, IAppDbContext
{
    ...

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync() => base.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```